# Facebook on Blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry

How do I retrieve id, username, and profile picture of my Facebook account via Facebook API for Blackberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using browserField and graph API.

register facebook application using some account. and get application id, secret , api key etc.

first call Api Oauth url to ask user for login. and show that link in browserfield. you dont need extended permission as you only require basic info.
second -- on call back from Oauth url after login success you get code. 
third -- use that code and using graph api request the access tocken .
fourth -- using this access tocken you can get id, picture, username, friends and other stuff. 
access tocken will have expiry as well.

there is a solution available [Download from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/files/)

above solution is using old authentication which may not work with your new applications. you have to modify the authentication part to work with oAuth and remove the REST api part.